# Recovering corrupted system files and apps without losing user data

Tags: android-11, troubleshooting

I have an Android phone that partially stopped working:

During a video call, the phone suddenly rebooted. After rebooting, some major system features were missing, and I can't seem to get the back to working.

The catch: I cannot try the usual solution of doing a factory reset to try to restore system files and apps that may have been corrupted. I moved from my home country, and this phone is used for access to bank accounts and such, which I cannot easily just reinstall, as I can't re-verify my identity in the apps.

**TL;DR**: Apps still work, but can't update them, and lost core system functionality, like the home button and notification area. Is it possible to recover them without losing my app data linked to the device?

## Details

### What stopped working

- General:

  1. Home button and app switching (buttons do nothing)
  2. Search bar *on Settings app* does not show up, only a blank gap
  3. Motorola's Gestures (shake to open Camera or Flashlight)
  4. Custom screenshot stuff
- Home Screen:

  1. Can't see notifications
  2. Corner shortcut icons for Camera disappeared
- Notification Area:

  1. Cannot expand area for more icons or see settings
  2. Lost settings customization
  3. Cannot see notifications
- Google Play Store

  1. Cannot find apps in the system (no pending updates, can't see installed/uninstalled lists)
  2. Cannot download new apps (stuck in "Pending")

### What still works

- General:

  1. Wi-Fi, Bluetooth, Apps
  2. Can access settings
  3. Volume, brightness (including adaptive), Camera, Lock button
  4. 2-button navigation's dragging upwards (it's the only way that allows me to reach home screen, from app screen)
  5. Back/Return button
  6. Install apps from their APKs
- Home Screen:

  1. Fingerprint and password login
  2. YouTube Music's play bar
- Notifications:

  1. Can see notifications inside the Settings app, in Notification history
  2. Can still hear the notification sounds + vibration
  3. Can open a very basic version of the notification area, with 6 default icons, which I can turn on or off
- Settings app:

  1. Can normally change settings back and forth
  2. Move files between phone and SD
  3. Clear app data and cache
  4. Start/stop apps
- Play Store:

  1. Search apps and see ads
  2. Google Play Protect
  3. The store app is able to update itself

### What I tried

1. Rebooting, multiple times
2. Rebooting into safe mode - Same system issues
3. Opening the bootloader's recovery mode and trying all options that weren't factory reset
4. Installing a new launcher app: it works, but no changes any errors
5. Resetting Google Play app to factory version and clearing all data

   - Google Play app was able to update itself, but it cannot find any app in the system
6. Clearing user data for multiple Google apps, like Google Play Services or App Customization
7. Uninstalling updates for Motorola's apps

### Phone details

- Model: Motorola One Vision (2019)
- OS: Android One 11

  - Version: RSAS31.Q1-48-36-23
  - Latest patch: May 1, 2022. I believe support has ended.

### Possible paths to a solution?

1. Reinstall system files without touching every other file

   - Can't perform a system update, as it seems to have no more support as of this year. But maybe rerun one, somehow?
2. Backup or transfer all app settings, with their accounts and verification status

   - to a new phone or Android VM; or
   - then hard reset the system on this phone, and safely restore the state

     - I realize this is possible with some backup apps, but I fear on the safety part, because I'd lose what I can still currently do in case it somehow fails
3. Verify integrity of storage of system files to restore safety, with a tool like Windows's `sfc /scannow` and `chkdsk /r`
4. Troubleshoot system dependencies

   - In case this is a corrupted app situation, find which service call is failing for the missing system functionality
   - Perhaps accessing logs from Play Store or when rebooting in safe mode? Or figuring out the external calls performed by the app for the installation process?
5. Anything else?

I'm open to suggestions for achieving these, or perhaps alternatives to recovering the functionality. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Backup or transfer of security apps like identification apps from a bank is usually prevented. Accessing the file-system to correct something requires root. So the only possible way would be o try to reinstall a full system image. Motorola doesn't seem to provide official download links for the image, so you may have to us an unofficial mirror like https://mirrors.lolinet.com/firmware/motorola/kane/official/ but there are dozen of variants for your phone. Those ZIPs should be installable via side-loading and recovery (requires connected PC).